Symfony Easyadmin how to create a crud DELETE for another entity
How in symfony EasyAdmin (https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/index.html) can I create a crud link to delete action for another entity (different crud controller) ?
This is the code that I need to change the entity:
 $deleteParticipantsAction = Action::new(
            TrainingParticipantCrud::DELETE_ACTION
        )
            ->setLabel("Delete Custom")
            ->linkToCrudAction(
                Action::Delete
            );

I tried the following code, but unfortunately when you click on the link symfony does not delete record (not start a dialogbox asking if you want to delete the record), but redirects to the home page.
  $deleteOrder = Action::new(
            TrainingParticipantCrud::DELETE_ORDER,
            "Delete Custom"
        )->linkToUrl(function (TrainingParticipant $d) {

        return $this->adminUrlGenerator
                ->unsetAll()
                ->setAction(Action::DELETE)
                ->setController(TrainingOrderCrudController::class)
                ->setEntityId($d->getTrainingOrder()->getId())
                ->generateUrl();
        });


By default, the delete button displays a modal to confirm the deletion of the record:
<form class="d-none" method="post" id="delete-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ ea_csrf_token('ea-delete') }}" />
</form>

See also https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/4.x/src/Resources/views/crud/includes/_delete_form.html.twig
If you add a button with a URL, the request isn't a POST request to the delete action.
For example, to delete a record, you must submit the delete form with the specific url:
<form action="{{ ea_url()
    .setController('App\\Controller\\Admin\\YourCrudController')
    .setAction('delete')
    .setEntityId(entity.id)
}} class="d-none" method="post" id="delete-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ ea_csrf_token('ea-delete') }}" />
</form>

